# Angular / rxjs : show download progress + wait for file to be downloaded before continueing

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

In an Ionic / Angular project I have a sequence of HTTP requests that need to complete before continuing.
But I also need to show the user a progressbar of the download in the app. But I can't figure out where or how to implement the listening for the HttpEvents so I can show the loading progress. This is what I currently have:

```
downloadDocument(document: Document) {
// does a http.get to get the documents url
return this.documentsRepositoryService.getDownloadUrl(document).pipe(
  concatMap(
    //the download url is received, now download the file.
    // TODO: listen for download progress and display 0 - 100% 
    // Should wait for download to complete
    dlUrl => this.documentsRepositoryService.downloadDocument(document, dlUrl.url)
  ),
  concatMap(
    value => {
      // do something with the downloaded file I suppose

      // Update the documentstatus to "downloaded"
      // returns promise, convert to observable
      document.download(); // just sets the document's state as downloaded
      return of(this.documentsRepositoryService.update(document));
    }
  ),
  concatMap(
    value => {
      // now do a httprequest to confirm to the api, the file is downloaded
      return this.documentsRepositoryService.confirmDownloadToAPI(document);
    }
  ),
  concatMap(
    value => {
      // sequence is done.
      this.setBadge();
      return value;
    }
  )

)
}
```

The method returns an observable I subscribe to :

```
onDownload(document) {

this.downloadManager.downloadDocument(document).subscribe(
  value => {
    // currently runs 
    console.log("downloaded");
  }
);
```

}

At the moment the "downloaded" console.log gets displayed 2 times, I suspect when the download starts and when it ends? So this is not the correct way to do it.

The few examples I find on this topic do the listening for the document download progress in a subscribe, but I don't know how to do this in a pipe or at least in a sequence.
Or is this a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Enough of the implementation here is hidden, but it looks like you've created a series of streams that emit one even each. So you really should end up with your subscription lambda being executed once. It will be worth some debugging time to figure out which call is generating two emissions.

Comment: If you're using a third party API to upload and/or download blobs of data, then how progress is relayed to you depends on the API. HTTP as a protocol doesn't come with download/upload progress built-in. Unless I'm missing something, this question isn't really answerable in the state it's in.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: still not "the" solution as the final object isn't received, only the messages of progress.

EDIT 2: Found it, the code below "changes" the result to the string in the function in the map().

I've found the answer in the official docs.
The error of running twice was because I didn't use the "last()" in the downloadFile method.It basically sent all events through.
The progress gets reported now.
Last thing to do is change code below so it doesn't send the string but the event itself.

```
downloadFile(filesrc) {
    const req = new HttpRequest('GET', filesrc, null, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'blob'
      
    });
   
    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
      map(event => this.getEventMessage(event)),
      tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
      last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
    );

  }
 
  showProgress(message ){
    console.log(message);
  }

  getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>) {
    console.log('event is', event);
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Sent:
        
        return `sending request`;

      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        // Compute and show the % done:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
       
        return `File is ${percentDone} uploaded.`;

      case HttpEventType.Response:
        
        return `File was completely uploaded!`;

      case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
        const percentDoneDL = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        
        return `File is ${percentDoneDL} downloaded`;

      case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
       
        return `Response headers are received`

      default:
        
        return `File surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`;
    }
  }
```